# Visual Studio 2015 "Hello World" Multiple Errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm using visual studio 2015 update 1 and I get 448 errors on my very simple console application. How can I fix these errors. I had not this problem before (visual studio 2013 was working properly.)

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;  

int main()  
{
    cout << "Hello World";  
    return 0;  
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: remove the "Precompiled header" check. I recommend even to check "Empty Project".

Comment: Just made a new project with your settings in MSVC 2015 and copy-pasted your code. It compiles exactly as it should. Did you change anything else? Any more code in your project?

Comment: @bolov How can I do this?

Comment: Check the empty project checkbox

Comment: @Mojtaba When you create a new project, like in your screenshots, there are those checkboxes.

Comment: @Anedar what is MSVC 2015?

Comment: @bolov 
I did your recommend but still have this problem

Comment: sry, meant to be msvs = microsoft visual studio

Comment: @Anedar Well now I'm using vs 2015

Comment: In the future, please tag questions like this correctly. It has almost nothing to do with C++ per se, but has to do with Visual whatever. Tagging it accordingly will help those who might answer. Thanks.

Comment: Your installation is probably broken or incomplete. I remember that some editions of MSVS required you to download an according SDK separately. Otherwise, I'd suggest you reinstall the whole thing. It's definitely not normal that a wizard-generated default project fails to compile.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt 
Yes, probably your guess is correct. This is not installed properly. thanks a lot

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thank you so much my problem solved as  you recommended :-)

Answer (score 1):

My problem solved by reinstalling visual studio update 1
[I thank this user: ulrich-eckhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968182/ulrich-eckhardt)

[image]